# UK/US dual citizen reentering US

Tags: usa, uk, customs-and-immigration

If a US/UK dual citizen re-enters US with a UK passport after a multiyear UK stay will this be detectable? IRS/Customs linkage and TECS system is cause for possible concern.

Comment: Why are you worried about whether it is "detectable"?

Comment: Have you got an ESTA already? If you apply for an ESTA you must disclose your US citizenship regardless, and it may be denied on the basis that by law you're supposed to use a US passport to enter the US.

Comment: Why is the IRS of concern here?

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP hopes to enter the US secretly so as to avoid tax liability.

Comment: Where were you born?

Answer (score 2):

The scenario you describe seems to be making more trouble for yourself than need be.

In order to enter the US with a UK passport you will need an ESTA (this applies to entry by all routes after October 1 2022). To apply for an ESTA you will need to declare all your citizenships, including your US one. If you state that you have US citizenship you will be denied an ESTA (since you don't need it). If you do not declare your US citizenship you will be guilty of deception, a crime that carries serious consequences even for a US citizen.

In any case your entry record will contain enough information that it can be linked to you and your US citizenship. Your US citizenship may not be immediately flagged at your entry, but anyone searching for your immigration records will be able to find out that you entered the US at the time you did. If you are looking to deceive authorities into thinking that you either did not leave the US, or did not enter the US, then that will almost certainly not stand up to any sort of scrutiny.

If the reason that you want to enter the US on your UK passport is that you do not have a current US passport then you are probably best off getting one.

Comment: "You may be able to get around this by flying to Canada or Mexico and then crossing into the US by land, in which case you would not need an ESTA." That will no longer be true [as of October 1](https://www.cbp.gov/newsroom/national-media-release/cbp-expands-esta-requirements-visa-waiver-program-travelers).

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: "If you state that you have US citizenship you will be denied an ESTA (since you don't need it)": it is not at all clear that this is correct.  I've seen reports by people that they've received ESTA authorization after disclosing US citizenship on the application.

Comment: Although failing to disclose US citizenship can be punished under 18 USC §1001 and possibly other laws, I think it's pretty unlikely that it actually would be punished, if the only reason why you do it is to enter the US.